# CQWP isn't showing all columns when accessing Anonymously

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, cqwp

i have created a CQWP with the following Xslt Template:

```
<xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0" >
   <select style="background-color:#3D3D3D; color:white; width:240px; font-size:16px; height:25px;
    font-weight:bold;">
    <option selected="selected" onclick="javascript:hideMissionDescriptionBox()"> choose </option>
     <xsl:if test="count(/*/Rows/Row) != 0">
       <xsl:for-each select="/*/Rows/Row">
       <option>
       <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
              javascript:FillMissionDescription(
              '<xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>',
              '<xsl:value-of select="@Email" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>',
              '<xsl:value-of select="@OfficeHours" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>',
              '<xsl:value-of select="@Weekends" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>',
              '<xsl:value-of select="@WebSite" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>',
              '<xsl:value-of select="@Region" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>',
              '<xsl:value-of select="@Country" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>',
              '<xsl:value-of select="@MissionType" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>',
              '<xsl:value-of select="@Address" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>')
             </xsl:attribute>

          <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="@Country" disable-output-escaping="yes">
          </xsl:value-of>
          &nbsp; - &nbsp;
          <xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes">
          </xsl:value-of>
          </p>
       </option>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:if>
     </select>
  </xsl:if>
```

The problem is when accessing as an Authorized user, it shows a drop down list with the actual data (works well), but when accessing Anonymously, it displays All the Data Except Some fields (Such as @Country).

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking in/Approving all the needed files solved the problem, the files are:

- Separate Js File
- XSL File
- The Page that hosts the Web Part that uses the XSL Template

previously, i was checking in/approving only Js and XSL Files